# How to run firefox and firefox ESR simultaneously

Tags: firefox, java

The main reason I want to use firefox ESR is to use a proprietary database tool for work that only allows oracle-java based web logins for linux (or a windows only thin client). I also want to use the full version of the outlook web application which only works in firefox. I don't want to run the NPAPI plugins for normal web browsing and email.

I have the repo version of firefox installed and firefox ESR installed in /opt/firefox and linked to /usr/local/firefox-esr

When I run firefox any attempt to run firefox-esr either brings up a window without the NPAPI plugins.

If I try running with the --new-instance or --no-remote options I receive the following error:

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

Regardless which one I start first, I can only open that one, and get the above error if I attempt to sidestep.

What makes this an especially annoying problem is that I often have to respond to emails that I need to access the database to deal with. So either I close and open many windows.

Comment: What error did the Windows-only thin client give when you attempted to run it in Wine?

Comment: You may also use the profile manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-no-remote` option, as in `firefox -no-remote`.

From `man firefox`:

> -no-remote
>
> Don't  connect  to any other running instances of firefox. Use this if you want to run firefox in an entirely new process. By
>   default, firefox will delegate a command to an already running
>   instance.

You'll also need separate profiles for Firefox and Firefox-esr, which can be created with with `firefox -P` Profile Manager.

Comment: I tried this, it's in my original post. Actually the firefox command line says --no-remote and the manual says -no-remote. I  tried both

Comment: This is interesting, have you tried creating a different or duplicate profile for the second firefox process? It works as expected here.

Comment: mikewhatever: that is interesting. What versions are you using? I'm in ubuntu 16.04. firefoxESR 52.0.2 (64bit) and firefox 52.0.02 (64bit).

Comment: Okay forget the versioning. Creating a new profile and manually loading them with the firefox -P works. If you want to put that in a solution I'll accept it.

Comment: `-no-remote`, `--no-remote` and `--new-instance` did not work for me, but running FF with `-P` did the trick! So I run `firefox-esr -P`, created a new profile for my esr and everything seem fine now.