# Simultaneous installation of Firefox legacy and Firefox Quantum?

Tags: software-installation, firefox

I do not want an update to kill all my add-ons, but also would like to enjoy the advantages of FireFoX qua**um.

**How can I install one of them next to the other one?**

Linux can be installed without overwriting Windows/default OS (some PCs ship FreeDos).
**But what about applications?**

Windows allows installing onto an alternative directory.

Comment: Firefox Quantum can't be used with older addons and older versions don't have the improvements of Firefox Quantum. Just so you know, installing two versions isn't going to change that.

Comment: I know, @ChaiT.Rex. That's why they should be installed separately but **both can run simultaneously.** Independently fron each others. Just like Chrome,Opera,Vivaldi,Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run firefox and firefox ESR simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904735/how-to-run-firefox-and-firefox-esr-simultaneously) and [How to install an old version of Firefox side-by-side to default version without conflicts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770740/how-to-install-an-old-version-of-firefox-side-by-side-to-default-version-without/770769#770769)